# Python Opencv video captures lags

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create motion detection alarm using opencv,webcam and python as a project.I created the motion detection and wanted to add features like mail alert and sms alert but when i call my mailing code the screen lags for about 5 sec.I need to alert user as soon as motion get detected.
Here's my code for Motion Detection

```
def detect(img, feed):
motiondetect = False
temp = img.copy()
contours, hierarchy = findContours(temp, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if len(contours) > 20 :
    motiondetect = True


else:
    motiondetect = False

return motiondetect


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
pr = False
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
recording = False
startr = True
send=True
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'IYUV')
count = 0
out = cv2.VideoWriter()
while True:
ret, img = cap.read()
if startr == True:
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("E:/vid" + str(count) + ".avi", fourcc, 6, (640, 480), 1)
    startr = False


img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 480))
grayimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, img2 = cap.read()
grayimg2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
diffimg = cv2.absdiff(grayimg, grayimg2)
m, thresimg = cv2.threshold(diffimg, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresimg = cv2.blur(thresimg, (10, 10))
n, thresimg = threshold(thresimg, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
motionn = detect(thresimg, img)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
mm = str(now.month)
dd = str(now.day)
yy = str(now.year)
hour = str(now.hour)
if (int(hour) < 10):
    hour = "0" + str(hour)
mi = str(now.minute)
if (int(mi) < 10):
    mi = "0" + str(mi)
ss = str(now.second)
if (int(ss) < 10):
    ss = "0" + str(ss)
pdt = dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yy + " " + hour + ":" + mi + ":" + ss
cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 460), (200, 480), (255, 255, 255), -1)
cv2.putText(img, str(pdt), (10, 473), font, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)
if (motionn == True):
    recording = True



else:
    recording = False
if (recording == True):
    out.write(img)
    cv2.putText(img, "Motion Detected", (0, 420), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)


imshow("Window", img)


k = waitKey(20)
if k == 27:
    break
elif k == 110:
    count = count + 1
    startr = True
elif k == 114:
    if (startr == False):
        startr = True

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

where should i call the mailing function?
Thanks for the help

Comment: run mailing function in other `thread`.

Comment: Ty for the prompt reply.Could u help with the code like  because i can't understand how to implement a mailing function in other thread while running the first thread.

Comment: example: http://pastebin.com/JdprnUiZ

Comment: Hi sir i added the threading still the lag is there.http://pastebin.com/hCCv1DyU ---the code ty again